# Column name getting changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, single-line-of-text

I have created 3 Single line of Text columns named L1, L2, L3

In list the display names show correctly, however internal name of column got generated as ***_x004c_1***

What could cause this? Is there any SP rule for naming which is getting applied?

Site column and root content type showing right name (L1), but list content type showing as ***_x004c_1*** internal name

Note: We create these columns programmatically using CSOM

Comment: Weird issues with the [internal names](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of SharePoint list columns. Try using longer column name like: `Level1`, `Level2`, etc. If you are doing it programmatically, it is easier to provide internal name & display name separately in code.

Comment: Yes, We have set internal and display names same while doing it programmatically. That's why I am more surprised to see it.

Comment: It creates such weird internal names even when you create list column from SharePoint UI, not only when you create it programmatically.